# Sonarqube Custom rule

Tags: php, sonarqube

I have a php code to check using sonarqube. I got how to create a new rule. I don't know hot to set rule for the php code. What should I do ?

Comment: +1 for the question, not sure why it's marked as unclear.

Answer (score 0):

In order to inspect PHP you have to install PHP inspector plugging.
So navigate to update are and search for a PHP plugin anf install it.
Then use the code as on its documentation.
http://docs.sonarqube.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/1966249